# element type invalid while trying twitter clone using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import "./SidebarOption.css";

function SidebarOption({ text, Icon }) {
return (
    <div className='sidebarOption'>
      <Icon />
      <h2>{text}</h2>
    </div>
 );
}


export default SidebarOption;
```

I am trying out Twitter clone whenever i type  I am getting this error
×
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: It looks like the "Icon" component you are passing in a prop is undefined. We'd have to see where you are using this component to help identify why this is happening

Comment: How is `SidebarOption` being used?